# AWK: Write lines into multiple files

Tags: regex, awk, substring, fasta

I'm trying to extract sequences from a FASTA file using awk.

e.g. the file looks like this and it contains 703 sequences. I want to extract each of them to separate files.

```
>sequence_1
AACTTGGCCTT
>sequence_2
AACTTGGCCTT
.
.
.
```

I'm using this awk script:

```
awk '/>/ {OUT=substr($0,2) ".fasta"}; OUT {print >OUT}'file.fasta
```

...which works but only for the 16 first and then I get an error saying;

```
.fasta makes too many open files
input record number 35, file file.fasta
source line number 1
```

Comment: -1 google it a bit, you will find stuff.

Comment: Thanks for editing the format. Trust me, I have googled the whole day trying to find different solutions for a bash oneliner. Any pointer would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't waste too much time pursuing for oneliner solutions. If you can solve a problem quickly with 10 lines, do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to close files when you're done. Try:

```
awk '/>/ {close(OUT); OUT=substr($0,2) ".fasta"}; OUT {print > OUT}' file.fasta
```